# access the tab which opened the new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm looking for a way to access the tab which opened new tab in javascript or jquery.
is there any way to do this?
I tried window.opener but it didn't work. :/
Is there any way?
I'm working with vue but I need a pure javascript way to solve this problem because I didn't work with vue-router in this project.

```js
// /my_desk
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      submodules: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.get_data();
  },
  methods:{
   get_data() {
    axios.get("/get_all_submodules")
    .then((data) => {
      // submodules get some value here
      this.submodules = data.data;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
   }
  }
})

// /action

new Vue({
  methods:{
    refresh_mydesk() {
      // I need to refresh the last tab which i opened to be refresh
      // I tried window.opener but it didn't work
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- "/my_desk" -->
<template>
  <div>
  <span id="refreshPage" @click="get_data()"></span>
    <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>code</th>
            <th>submodules</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <thead>
          <tr v-for="item in submodules" :key="item.id">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.code}}</td>
            <td>
              <a :href="'/action?id='+item.id" target"_blank">
                {{item.submodules.count}}
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<!-- "/action?id={id_of_action}" -->
<template>
  <a href="#" @click="refresh_mydesk()">
    Refresh my desk
  </a>
</template>
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: Provide minimal code to see what you have done so far and so others can help.

Comment: @battaboombattabaam here is my code

Comment: How about a `_blank`? Example: `window.open('https://www.google.com/, '_blank')`;